# Java profiling with varying machines

Tags: java, profiling

What the best way to reduce the impact the underlying machine of a Java program has on any profiling measurement?

I have different results for profiling each time I run my program, mostly because the machine I run my program on has varying load as a whole.  It's also connected to the machine being a VM, and the hypervisor returning me different VMs each time I ask for one, but that's not the point.

The point is:

Is there a way to profile a Java execution regardless of the speed of the machine the Java program runs on?  Is there maybe some other measurement (like JVM-steps through the bytecode or similar?) than just the plain old nanoseconds?

I know this will be problematic about the native stuff you will eventually jump into, but that could be handled differently.  I'm just concerned about "my" code and that's pure Java.

Answer (score 1):

Look at percents, not absolute time. Look at inclusive, never exclusive percent. Look at wall-clock percent, not CPU percent, if you can.  If possible, look at inclusive percent for lines, not just methods. Don't be too concerned about "accuracy" - you're looking for things that have a high percent. Exactly how high is beside the point.

Comment: Actually I'm looking for changes in a very large project over time, based on results of just unit tests.  They are supposed to be not typical usage (of course) of the functions, so I cannot rely solely on looking at the large numbers.  Think of a continuous profiling to find unwanted reductions of performance quickly.  In this scenario, when regression tests show performance reductions, I'd like to view the profiling results to find the culprit.

Comment: @Alfe: My expertise is more in how to find possible speedups. Unfortunately, I don't know a way to regression-test speed without holding the hardware and other things constant. However, it would seem to be worthwhile to profile inclusive percents, with enough samples to hold down the uncertainty, and then look for changes in that from time to time. Some function might change its inclusive percent by a fairly large amount, and that could be a red flag, to do some investigating there.